# Control state store Locally/Cookies using Knockout js /JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application with knockoutjs and jquery.

I want to save the state of the control in local storage/cookie.

Is there any plugin available to store locally/Cookies?

Comment: what you exactly "mean by state of the control" ?

Answer (score 1):

I use [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Its easy to use and versatile.

Answer (score 0):

i don't fully understand what you want to accomplish, but you can use [amplifyjs](http://amplifyjs.com/) to store data locally

> Client Side Browser & Mobile Device Storage - amplify.store takes the
>   confusion out of HTML5 localStorage. It doesn't get simpler than using
>   amplify.store(key, data)! It even works flawlessly on mobile devices.